# Answer for an application for an unadvertised job

Tags: communication, job-search, hiring, cover-letter, feedback

I applied via a form to a company for an unadvertised job. In this form, you have to write a cover letter about what can you bring in the company what is your idea. So I applied and I wrote a cover letter obviously. **Keep in mind that this answer wasn't replied instantly but I received it after 2 days** The answer was the below :

> "Hello ---------,
>
> Thank you for taking the time to apply for a future opening at ---------. I would like to confirm that we've received your application in good order.
>
> Once a future opening that matches your profile is available, we will reach out to you.
>
> In the meantime, feel free to contact me with any questions you might have.
>
> Thanks again for applying!
>
> All the best
>
> ---
>
> Executive Administrator

So I want your opinion about whether or not this is a typical answer and about the :

> In the meantime, feel free to contact me with any questions you might have.

What is the meaning of this, what can I ask or what they expected from this?
Since I didn't apply for a specific job.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Their response seems pretty straight-forward - contact them if you have (good) questions. Don't contact them if you don't have questions. We wouldn't be able to list all possible things you can ask in response to that, nor tell you how any given question may affect your application (positively or negatively), nor tell you whether they're just saying that to be polite or whether they actually mean it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a boilerplate template.

The Executive Assistant probably didn't even read what she sent you. Don't read anything into it, good or bad. It just means they've received your cover letter and resume. That's it.

The timing doesn't mean anything either. She could just have been enjoying an extra long memorial day weekend. Or she could just be doing her work in batches, with the most important work first and the least important work when she's not too busy.

You're dedicating too much mental energy to this one job application. Stop doing that. Use all that extra energy and time you have to apply to more jobs.